# IRB console and rails application evaluates 'or' differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean, irb

In my attempts to write code with high readability I have been using the `or` and `and` operators as synonyms for `||` and `&&`. Though, now I have come to the understanding that `or` and `and` have a diffrent application. http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

The confusing thing is the difference when running the following code in my rails application and the IRB console.

In IRB:

```
var = false or true
# => true
```

In my rails application:

```
var = false or true
# => false
```

In short is seems like `or` doesn't have the same precedence level in IRB and in the actual rails application. This is confusing and misleading. Is there any reason for it?

Comment: How did you check it in actual application?

Comment: That can't be correct.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked in my own app, `var = false or true` is evaluating to true.

Comment: @MarekLipka in a random, pretty isolated class, I entered the above code and `puts` the output it in my console. Are you telling me that assignment shouldn't have precedence over `or`?

Comment: Please don't use imaginary code. Show a real (but minimal) example that runs. The code you posted should always evaluate as true.

Comment: @Mikael don't use `or`. use `||`. `or` is a path to sadness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the results. There should be no difference in the way an expression is interpreted in irb and rails. When you do:

```
var = false or true
```

it is interpreted as:

```
(var = false) or true
```

after which the value of `var` is `false`, and whose return value is `true`. Since irb returns the return value of the expression, you will get `true`. And if in your rails app you check the value of `var`, that should be evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Of course this is the case. I was misinterpreting the IRB. Thank you.